# Android Google Play TurnBasedMatch- Not a valid turn status: 4

Tags: google-play-games

I have been working on developing a turn-based multiplayer game. Everything had been working fine for quite a while, until suddenly I can no longer open the intent for the "Match inbox" (eg,

```
Intent intent = getGamesClient().getMatchInboxIntent();
startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.RC_LOOK_AT_MATCHES);
```

When I look at the error's stack trace, it is because there is a match with an invalid state.
What's worse, is that even when I try to load the matches to simply delete/dismiss them all programmatically, I also get the error:

```
02-05 07:43:36.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 07:43:36.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13814): Process: com.oakonell.ticstacktoe, PID: 13814
02-05 07:43:36.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13814): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a valid turn status: 4
02-05 07:43:36.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13814):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1473)
02-05 07:43:36.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13814):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
02-05 07:43:36.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13814):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.fc$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
02-05 07:43:36.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13814):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ex.a(Unknown Source)
02-05 07:43:36.684: E/AndroidRuntime(13814):    at com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient.loadTurnBasedMatches(Unknown Source)
```

(It looks like the constants for the MATCH_TURN_STATUS_* run from 0-3, so 4 is invalid.)

Besides the fact that the API somehow allowed me, in ignorance, to save a match in an invalid state, it appears that once there is one in an invalid state, it can't ever be referenced, even if to clean it up.

I saw that the developers console references an API to reset matches for a (whitelisted) user.

```
https://cloud.google.com/console/project/[app id]/apiui/api/gamesManagement/method/gamesManagement.turnBasedMatches.reset
```

But I couldn't get this to work from within the console itself (I was also uncertain how to specify the user(s)). Is there a way to access this from the Android app code? Otherwise, how would I access from the Console to reset the matches for the (tester) players affected by this invalid match?

Comment: I guess a secondary question would be, how did I even save a match in an invalid turn status, and how to prevent that in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "disconnect" the app, deleting all google data, from my user.
Go to Device Settings | Accounts | Google.
Click on Google+, choose the user with the broken match under account settings, click Apps with Google+ Sign-In, choose the app with the broken match, and finally click disconnect.

When the dialog comes up to confirm, check the "Also delete all your (App) activities on Google, and click Disconnect to confirm.

This didn't immediately seem to fix the problem, I also cleared the devices' "Google Play Services" cache. Go to Device Settings | Application Manager, find "Google Play services" and click it. For this App, clear data/cache, Manage Data, whatever you can to delete all local cached data (I don't think this can harm any other apps using Google Play services, as you should be able to eg, install the app on a new device and have it sync to your cloud saved state. OK, perhaps this could delete pending changes that haven't been sent to the cloud yet... use with caution.) This one may not have been required to perform in order for my user's "match intent" to work again, but as I say, it didn't seem to immediately work after the app disconnect, and relogging in. It either took time for the disconnect to propagate across the cloud(?) or I also had to clear the device's cache...

Now to hope that I don't someone save any matches with an invalid state, in some manner.
This solution certainly beat waiting the two weeks that I thought was my other option, waiting for the match to expire after no activity from the two users.

(I suppose a third option for how this was fixed was that some "cleanup" job was ran on the google servers to delete/correct any invalid matches, either periodically or in response to either this stackoverflow question or an email/crash report I sent when my device's "Google Play services stopped responding".)